# Can I mock objects creation inside tested code with gMock?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a code like this one:

```
void ClassA::Function()
{
    ClassB b;
    if (b.doSomething())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And mock for classB:

```
class ClassBMock: public classB
{
    MOCK_METHOD(doSomething, bool(void));
}
```

Is it possible to test this function, having ClassBMock created instead of ClassB, so I can use EXPECT_CALL and control what doSomething returns?

Answer (score 1):

No, if you instantiate an object of type `ClassB` in the context of your to-be-tested function, the compiler (and linker) will make sure that you get an object of type `ClassB` ;)

What you can do to get an instance of your mock class instead, is e.g. by means of a [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), [factory function](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Factory_function&redirect=no) or you simply pass a pointer to the object `b` as a parameter to `Function()`. This way you can inject a mock object, when the code is tested.

Luckily we are talking about C++, so there is one further possible way:  Provide a different definition of `class ClassB` in case `ClassA::Function()` is compiled/linked in the test context.
I.e. you need to have a different "build-tree" when building the test. Here you can refer to the source file of the productive source-tree, that contains the to-be-tested method. **But** you can include a different header with the mock definition of `ClassB` instead of the productive one. In case `ClassB` is defined in some other library, you link a mock version of it.

All this is not specific for GMock.

What GMock can do for you is summarized nicely in this [Cookbook](https://github.com/abseil/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md). You can see in virtually any case the construction of the mock/fake object is done in the context of the test coding. It then needs to be "injected" in the to-be-tested code in some way as described above.